# Promote Jar file from Snapshot to Release

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

My user is receving the following error when promoting a JAR file from snapshot repository to release repository using artifactory promotion plugin. Please help on how to avoid this error.

```
Performing dry run promotion (no changes are made during dry run) ...

    ERROR: Promotion failed during dry run (no change in Artifactory was done): HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
    {
      "messages" : [ {
        "level" : "ERROR",
        "message" : "The repository 'XXXXXX' rejected the path 'XX/XX/XXXXX/XX/XXXX/2.1-SNAPSHOT/malin-modular-2.1-20180125.094354-1.jar' due to a conflict with its snapshot/release handling policy."
      }, {
        "level" : "INFO",
        "message" : "Skipping promotion status update: item promotion was completed with errors and warnings."
      } ]
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Little information to guess the reason but assuming this is with Maven repositories...

Each repository is configured to receive either:

- only snapshots (i.e. version ends with "-SNAPSHOT" or a timestamp)
- only releases (any version except if it ends with "-SNAPSHOT" or a timestamp)
- both snapshots and releases (any version is accepted, I don't really recommend this)

This is configured in the details of the local repository, see [this page](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Local+Repositories#LocalRepositories-Maven,Gradle,IvyandSBTRepositories)

When you configure your promotion, you configure a move from a repository to another, but you still have to respect the capabilities of your repositories.

So my guess is that you are trying to promote a snapshot version to a repository that only accepts release versions

I suggest you that you set up

- a snapshot local repository (e.g. 'dev')
- a release local repository (e.g. 'release')
- a release local repository for promoted element (e.g. 'gold')

And use

- 'dev' to push the results of your continuous build on your CI
- 'release' to push the results of your release process on your CI
- 'gold' as the target of your promotion process from 'release' to 'gold'

Comment: Thanks. You are correct. The 'release' repository can handle only release artifacts. Is there are way to promote files from snapshot to release or gold repositories.

Comment: I would not recommend promoting snapshots. That's a bad idea because you will promote something that may not be tagged / traced properly... If you really want to do that... You will need to combine a move (changing the version) with a promotion.